# Why does one need a null shared_ptr and how can it be used?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, effective-c++

In Scott Meyers's *Effective C++*, item 18 *Make interfaces easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly*, he mentioned the null shared_ptr:

```
std::tr1::shared_ptr<Investment> pInv(static_cast<Investment*>(0), getRidOfInvestment)
```

and a vogue assignment operation

```
pInv = ...     //make retVal point to the correct object
```

In which case one may need to create a null shared_ptr and do assignment later? Why not just create the shared_ptr whenever you have the resources (raw pointer)?

Since Scott Meyers did not show the complete assignment in the previous example, I thought the shared_ptr's assign operator is overloaded that one can do this:

```
pInv = new Investment;    // pInv will take charge of the pointer
                          // but meanwhile keep the delete function it already had
```

But I tried with **boost**'s implementation it doesn't work this way. Then what is the sense to have null shared_ptr?

I am almost sure that I am missing something here, someone help me out of it please.

ps. more about the initialization and assignment of a shared_ptr

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr1(new int);
    boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr2;
    ptr2.reset(new int);
    boost::shared_ptr<int> ptr3 = new int;

    return 0;
}
```

this example can not be compiled by **g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2** and the latest boost:

```
sptr.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
sptr.cpp:8:39: error: conversion from ‘int*’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::shared_ptr<int>’    requested
```

Comment: I tried to figure it out here: http://ideone.com/BUjOwZ. I couldn't come up with an explanation.

Comment: As others have pointed out, there are plenty of reasons to need a null shared_ptr, just like you have null raw pointers. But the real mystery is why Scott felt the need for it to have a custom deleter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no need to use that hack to get a null (empty) `shared_ptr`. Simply use the default constructor:

```
std::shared_ptr<Investment> pInv; // starts null
```

To assign a pointer to a `shared_ptr`, either do it at construction time:

```
std::shared_ptr<Investment> pInt(new Investment);
// not allowed due to explicit annotation on constructor:
// std::shared_ptr<Investment> pInt = new Investment;
```

Or use the `.reset()` function:

```
pInt.reset(new Investment);
```

It's possible that the author of that article may have intended to provide a custom deleter  (`getRidOfInvestment`). However, the deleter function is reset when `.reset()` is called, or when otherwise the inner pointer is changed. If you want a custom deleter, you must pass it to `.reset()` upon creation of the `shared_ptr`.

One pattern you might want to use to make this more foolproof is a custom creation function:

```
class Investment {
protected:
  Investment();
  // ...
public:
  static shared_ptr<Investment> create();
};

shared_ptr<Investment> Investment::create() {
  return shared_ptr<Investment>(new Investment, getRidOfInvestment);
}
```

Later:

```
shared_ptr<Investment> pInv = Investment::create();
```

This ensures you will always have the correct destructor function attached to the `shared_ptr`s created from `Investment`s.

Comment: The example givien in the quetion, the reason for the null pointer in the constructor call is the use of a custom deleter. The constructor for the smart pointer doesn't have a version that only takes the custom deleter, hence the need for the "hack".

Comment: "std::shared_ptr<Investment> pInt = new Investment;" can't be compiled

Comment: oops, looks like it's an explicit constructor.

Comment: anyway, because when you reset the pointer the custom deleter will also be reset, right? then the null shared_ptr with a custom deleter completely make no sense in real programming, so weird to have such an example in such a nice book

Comment: It's worth noting that `shared_ptr` has only recently been standardized, and it's possible that it may have had different semantics at some other point in the standardization process (although I kind of doubt it...)

Comment: I assumed I was missing something, I refused to believe Scott could be mistaken! But this is the only explanation I can come up with, +1

Comment: Note you can now more easily write a null `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter using `std::shared_ptr<Investment> pInv(nullptr, getRidOfInvestment)` but I'm not sure why you would want to.

Answer (score 7):

It's the same reason to have a null raw pointer - e.g.

say you have:

```
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Investment> InvestmentPtr;
map<key,InvestmentPtr> portfolio;
...
get(mykey) {
  iterator it = portfolio.find(mykey);
  if (it == portfolio.end()) 
    return InvestmentPtr();
  else 
    return it->second;
  }
}
```

This allows you to do:

```
InvestmentPtr p = get(key);
if (p) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of reasons you might like objects to be default constructible. First and foremost you'd like the smart pointer to be as similar as possible to a raw pointer, and since you can say `int * p;` (and get an undefined, uninitialized pointer), you can also say `shared_ptr<int> p;` and get a pointer that doesn't point anywhere (but you get to test it with `!`).

One of the most compelling reasons is possibly that you can make containers with `shared_ptr`s, and you can fill the containers without assigning pointees right there and then.